# Saving numeric data in a file

Tags: r, file

I am generating huge amount of data and would like to store only selected values during my run. But it always saves last result. For example, in the following sample code it always store last result satisfying my condition. Remember that I have huge data and don't want to store in vector or list but would like to store right away in a file. I need your help.

Thanks.

```
f<-function(x) (x-1)*(x-5)*(x-10)

fileE<-file("E.txt")
for (i in seq(1,100,0.1)){
   if (f(i) > 0 && f(i) < 10)
      writeLines(paste0(i,"   ",f(i)), fileE)
}
close(fileE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `write` with append:

```
unlink("E.txt")

for (i in seq(1, 100, 0.1)){
  res <- f(i)
  if (res > 0 & res < 10)
    write(x = paste0(i, " ", res), file = "E.txt", append = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: This works, but if I run my simulation again it will append data in previous existing file. How can I erase previous data and start appending new one?

Comment: No, it still adds into previous data file and does not remove previous contents.

Comment: `unlink` file to delete it between runs. (Or `if (i == 1) unlink("E.txt")` inside your loop.)

Comment: This works. I used unlink("E.txt") outside the loop.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to write if condition inside loop, it will take some processing time for huge sequence. I used only unlink("E.txt") before loop and it works.